# Verifying a text on a dialog box with Cypress and Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd

I'm trying to verify a text message on a dialog box using cypress and cucumber. The test cases are working perfectly fine when it's within "it function". Here is is the sample code :

```
    it ('Verify if the Login is successful', function()
    {
       
        cy.visit('loginTest.html')
        cy.get('#username').type('shahin')
        cy.get('#password').type('tala')
        cy.contains('Login').click() 
        cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
            expect(str).to.equal(`Login Successfully`)
          })
    })
```

However when i add the BDD keywords it looks like the function doesn't get evaluated at all. **It works for When but not the Then scenario**. I think it needs to be handled in Js in a different way. I have uploaded the cypress log as well. Below is the code :

```
        When('I click on the login button', () => {
            cy.contains('Login').click()
        })
        Then('Successful POP up message should be displayed', () => {
            cy.on('window:alert',  (str) =>  {
                expect(str).to.equal(`Login Successfully`)

            })
```

Cypress Log

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is `cy.on('window:alert'...` is a passive event listener, it does not do anything until an event is emitted by the app.

This means you need to set it before the event is triggered (e.g Login click),

```js
When('I click on the login button', () => {
  cy.on('window:alert', ...something here...)   // set up the event listener
  cy.contains('Login').click()                  // action that triggers the event
})
```

If you do your `expect()` within the callback of the event listener it mucks up your BDD flow (`Then()` is redundant).

Use a stub to catch the event, and assert the stub properties inside `Then()`.

```js
let stub  // declare outside so it's visible in both When and Then

When('I click on the login button', () => {
  stub = cy.stub()              // set stub here (must be inside a test)
  cy.on('window:alert', stub)   // capture call 
  cy.contains('Login').click()  
})

Then('message is displayed', () => {
  expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith('Login Successful')
})
```

---

**Why does it() work?**

Essentially, with `it()` all the code is within one block vs two blocks for `When()` `Then()`.

The async commands are queued for later exectution, but the synchronous `cy.on()` is executed immediately - even though it's the last line it gets executed first.

```js
it('...', () => {

  // Queued and executed (slightly) later
  cy.visit('loginTest.html')
  cy.get('#username').type('shahin')
  cy.get('#password').type('tala')
  cy.contains('Login').click() 

  // executed immediately (so actually first line to run)
  cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
    expect(str).to.equal(`Login Successfully`)
  })
})
```

The `When()` and `Then()` blocks are executed in sequence, so you don't get the same pattern as with `it()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.